# Triangle with sides less than $1$.

Tags: geometry

If the triangle sides are less than $1$, what is the maximum value of the area?

I'm in doubt between using $A=\frac12\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot \sin a$, or using heron's formula.

Comment: yes using A=(1/2)*1*1*sina, the max of sina Is 1 so the maxA = 1/2 but if sina=1 isn't a=90, that means that the other side is larger than 1?

Comment: Consider first the case where the sides are $\le1$. wlog we can take $BC=1$. Hence $A$ must lie inside the circles radius 1 centres $B,C$. The area is the base $BC$ times the height, so we maximise the area by taking $A$ at one of the two points of intersection of the circles, giving an equilateral triangle area $\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$. Now for sides less than 1, we can get as close as we like to this figure, but we cannot realise it.

Answer (score 1):

We know-from the Isoperimetric Theorem-that among all triangles with the same perimeter, the one with the largest area is the equilateral.

So, let's assume that you have an equilateral trianlge of side $a\lt1$

The area of an equilateral triagle of side $a$ is given by $$A=\frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2$$

For $a=1$, we get $A=\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$. Thus the desired area, $S$ is $$S\lt\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$$

Comment: Yes, I got the same answer using heron formula, thanks!

Comment: @dsa12341 Glad it helped!